# How to combine some files with different sizes into one excel file using shell?

Tags: bash, shell, merge, paste

I have these files, and I want to merge them in an excel file
each file have two columns

file1

```
title1
 1 1 
 2 2 
 3 3
```

file2

```
title2
 5 5
 6 6 
 7 7
 8 8 
 9 9
 10 10
```

file 3

```
title3
21 21
22 22
23 23
24 24
```

i use command below to merge them in a excel file

```
paste file* > out.csv
```

the normal output is ok,but when i put it in an excel file(out.csv), the output become like this

```
title1 title2 title3
1  1   5  5   21  21
2  2   6  6   22  22
3  3   7  7   23  23
   8  8   24  24
   9  9
  10 10
```

but **I want this output**

```
title1 title2 title3
1  1   5  5   21  21
2  2   6  6   22  22
3  3   7  7   23  23
       8  8   24  24
       9  9 
       10 10
```

each number should be in separate cells, separate columns and exactly below each other
but when the size of a file is longer than the previous file, the additional numbers go back to last column and below the previous file numbers, for example numbers 8,9,10 and 24

Comment: The default delimiter for `paste` is a `TAB` character.  You need to ensure that your input file(s) use the same separator.

Comment: I try it.It doesn't work

Comment: I tested `paste file*`, it gave exactly what you were expecting... (`paste 8.21`)

Comment: yes,but when i open it by excel,they pirnt irregular

Comment: @MRS89 oh.. that I cannot test...I don't have MS-Excel installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxLines=$(wc -l file1 file2 file3 | grep -v total | sort -nr | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
for f in file1 file2 file3
do
    sed 's/ /,/g' "$f" > "$f".tmp
    lineCount=$(wc -l < $f.tmp)
    linesToAdd=$((maxLines-lineCount))
    for ((i=0;i<linesToAdd;i++))
    do
        echo "," >> "$f".tmp
    done
done
paste -d, file{1,2,3}.tmp | sed '1 s/,/,,/g'
rm file*.tmp
```

Output:

```
$ myscript.sh
title1,,title2,,title3
1,1,5,5,21,21
2,2,6,6,22,22
3,3,7,7,23,23
,,8,8,24,24
,,9,9,,
,,10,10,,
```

The script works by calculating the max number of lines in the files and then appending extra rows to the other files. For example, in this case, `file2` has 7 rows and `file1` has 4, so the script will temporarily add an extra 3 comma-delimited rows to `file1`. Finally, `paste` is used to merge the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#/bin/bash
maxcount=`read wc -l file1  file2  file3 | sort -h -r | sed -rn '2s/^ *([0-9]+).*/\1/'`
exec 4<file1
exec 5<file2
exec 6<file3
while [ $maxcount -gt 0 ]; do
    read -a f1<&4
    read -a f2<&5
    read -a f3<&6
    echo ${f1[0]},${f1[1]},${f2[0]},${f2[1]},${f3[0]},${f3[1]}
    ((maxcount--))
done
exec 4<&-
exec 5<&-
exec 6<&-
```

I have hard-coded max columns for each file as 2.
However, if that varies, you can get max column for each file & run a loop with `echo -n ${f1[$i]}`

Comment: tnx anishsane . I'll use it.